# Insert date into database using Prepared Statement

Tags: jsp, date, prepared-statement

I want to insert a date of the format YYYY-MM-DD which is entered by the user into the database using Prepared Statement in JSP by this way:

```
 SimpleDateFormat reFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD") 
 Date activityDate = reFormat.parse(request.getParameter("activity_date"));
 java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(activityDate.getTime());

 String query = "INSERT INTO schedule(login_name,activity_date) VALUES (?, ?)";
 PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
 stmt.setString(1,request.getParameter("name_of_user"));
 stmt.setDate(2,sqlDate);
 stmt.executeUpdate();
```

however, if the user enter for example: 2012-06-22  in the database a wrong date 2012-01-01 is saved instead of 2012-06-22

Is anyone know what is the problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format is `yyyy-MM-dd`. `Y` doesn't mean anything, and `D` means day of year (instead of day of month).